# How to get email address on facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a Facebook app and downloaded facebook-php-sdk-master file from facebook. It is working great it is just i need the email address of the people who use our app.. and it does not return the email address... i made some research and a youtube video said to request it on getLoginUrl

```
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('email'=>'email'));
}
```

but still doest return the email address. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not correct. You're requesting the permission to read the user's e-mail address. Any permission requests should be made with the `scope` field, like so:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
   'scope' => 'email'
));
```

The above code will create the URL. Now, to direct users to this URL, you can use the following code:

```
<a href="<?=$loginUrl;?>">Login</a>
```

When a user clicks on the above link, they'll be asked to supply the permission for reading their emails.

If you want additional permissions, you can request it the same way. Just add them to the `scope` field as comma-separated values. The full list of permissions, including defaults, [can be found in the Facebook Developers documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference).